# What is the average distance between points in a circle that lies on a sphere?

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, average, spheres

For a sphere of radius R with a circle of intrinsic radius r on it, what would the average intrinsic distance be between points in that circle? I'm as interested in approaches/methods as I am in the actual solution. Is there a way to do something like that for n-balls on n-spheres? Any insights in how this would generalise to hyperbolic geometry also welcome.

Comment: Two comments: 1. The question is not well defined, because there are many points on the circle and it isn't clear between which points you wish to measure the distance. 2. The intrinsic distance between any two points in the circle is independent of their surroundings - it is the same Euclidean distance everywhere so you can assume that the circle lies in a plane.

Comment: When you talk of intrinsic distances do you mean distances as measured on a great circle of the sphere?  It would be the same for any one point at the end, so just pick a point for one end of the distance and integrate over the circle for the other.  I'm sure there is a moderately handy formula.

Comment: I said in the circle not on (ESL so maybe language barrier, but in my experience, those mean different things) Also to uniquesolution if you were to pick two random points at most distance r from some centre point what is the expected value of their distance as a function of r and R? I also don't see how this would be independent of curvature which distorts distances(as well as the very notion of a circle)